# The data grid is out of the frame Angular 14

Tags: angular

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
     <mat-tab label="BILL">
          <mat-card>
               <!--com 2-->
               <mat-card class="mt-2">
                    <mat-card-content>
                         <app-pur-pr-list-assign-com2 #c2></app-pur-pr-list-assign-com2>

                    </mat-card-content>

               </mat-card>
          </mat-card>
     </mat-tab>
     <mat-tab label="Upload">
          <mat-card>
               <mat-card>
                    <!-- app upload com3 -->
                    <app-pur-pr-list-assign-com-upload #comupload></app-pur-pr-list-assign-com-upload>

               </mat-card>
          </mat-card>

     </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

how can i fix it?
It's out of Mat-Card.
I tried putting `class="w-100"` and it didn't work.
[image]

HTML app-pur-pr-list-assign-com2

```
<form [formGroup]="PrlnService.form">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered w-100">
        <thead style="text-align: center;">
            <th *ngIf="false">prno</th>
            <th >No</th>
            <th>Descliption</th>
            <th >Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Req date</th>
            <th>Over 1 Year</th>
            <th>Credit Tem Code </th>
            <th>Acc Code </th>
            <th>Sub Acc Code </th>
            <th>Action </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody formArrayName="prdetail" name="prdetail" >
            <tr *ngFor="let newPR of this.PrlnService.prdetail.controls; let i = index " [formGroupName]="i">
                <td *ngIf="false">
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>prno </mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="prno">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <p style="margin-top: 20px;">{{i+1}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>descliption</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="des">
                    </mat-form-field>

                </td>
                <td >
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>price</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="number" name="price" formControlName="price"
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>qty</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="number" name="qty" formControlName="qty"
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>unit</mat-label>
                        <select matNativeControl formControlName="unit" name="unit">
                            <option value="">--</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let unit of  this.PrlnService.units" [value]="unit.unit">
                                {{unit.unit}} | {{unit.unitname}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="this.PrlnService.selectedUnitC.hasError('required')">Please choose
                            requires
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>amount</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" name="amount" formControlName="amount" readonly
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Req date dd/MM/yyyy</mat-label>
                        <input matInput name="reqdate" formControlName="reqdate" type="text" [matDatepicker]="picker"
                            required>

                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <section class="example-section mt-3">
                        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Checked</mat-checkbox>
                    </section>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Credit Tem Code</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" name="creditTC" formControlName="creditTC"
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Sub Acc Code</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" name="acccode" formControlName="acccode"
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Credit Tem Code</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" name="subacccode" formControlName="subacccode"
                            (change)="this.PrlnService.onControlChange($event, i)">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class=" w-100  mt-3 mb-2 justify-content-center" mat-raised-button color="primary"
                        type="button" (click)="this.PrlnService.remove_Pr_n(i)">
                        Remove
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button color="primary" mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="this.PrlnService.addPr_n()">
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz or something similar?

Comment: my stackblitz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6p9sll?file=src/app/pur/com1/com1.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is simply a overflow problem. Add a class to the `form` containing the table and add this to the class:

```
.yourClass {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

for further information about overflow visit [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)